# AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'get_texture'

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm having a problem with the player class I've created. To create it I was inspired by how I was doing on Pygame, so maybe that's why I'm getting the error here on Pyglet.

```
class player(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, game):
        self.game = game
        self.groups = self.game.spritesPlayer
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = pyglet.resource.image("white_square.png")
        self.rect.x = x * self.game.tilesize
        self.rect.y = y * self.game.tilesize
```

The class is called from the main class with `self.player = player(self, 0, 0)`

And this is the Player group contained in the main class: `self.spritesPlayer = OrderedDict()`

The error I'm getting is this:

```
    File "C:/Users/BlackFenix06/Desktop/pk.py/c.py", line 464, in __init__
    pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 243, in __init__
    self._texture = img.get_texture()
AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'get_texture'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm working for 2D, not for 3D

Comment: What is `self.game.spritesPlayer`?  It seems to be an `OrderedDict`.  However, the `Sprite.__init__` method needs a Pyglet image or animation as its first parameter.

Comment: At the moment in my script there are two classes, one is the main one (where the program runs), the second one is the Player one."self.group = self.game.spritesPlayer" the Player class picks up the group that is contained in the main class ("self.spritesPlayer = OrderedDict ()")

Comment: The error is saying that you can't pass `self.groups` to `Sprite.__init__`, because it's not an image nor an animation.

Comment: So how can I solve?

Comment: As I have said before, you need to pass an image (or an animation) to `Sprite.__init__`.  You can't pass some other random object to `Sprite.__init__` and expect Pyglet to somehow figure out what you want. [This page](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/image.html) describes how to create images in Pyglet.